SQL full outer join, default value to column in other table
I'm attempting to do a full outer join in Postgres to see how data changes between the past 24 hours and the 24 hours before that ("today" and "yesterday" euphemistically). Some values only exist on one side of the join, in that case I'd like to use the value from the other side of the join.
Current result with below query:



Today Type
Today Count
Yesterday Type
Yesterday Count




REPORT_A
2
REPORT_A
5


REPORT_B
4






REPORT_C
6



What I would like the output to be:



Today Type
Today Count
Yesterday Type
Yesterday Count




REPORT_A
2
REPORT_A
5


REPORT_B
4
REPORT_B
0


REPORT_C
0
REPORT_C
6



For REPORT_B I'd like its values propagated to the right side and for REPORT_C I'd like its values propagated to the left side. How do I do this?
WITH
  yesterday_report_count AS (
    SELECT
      "reports"."report"."type" AS "type",
      "reports"."report"."status" AS "status",
      COUNT(*) AS "count"
    FROM
      "reports"."report"
    WHERE
      "reports"."report"."requested_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS' AND NOW()
    GROUP BY
      "reports"."report"."type",
    ORDER BY
      "count" DESC,
      "reports"."report"."type" ASC,
  )


SELECT 
yesterday_report_count.type as "Today Type",
yesterday_report_count.count "Today Count",
today_report_count.type as "Yesterday Type",
today_report_count.count as "Yesterday Count"
FROM
  yesterday_report_count
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT
      "reports"."report"."type" AS "type",
      COUNT(*) AS "count"
    FROM
      "reports"."report"
    WHERE
    1=1
    AND "reports"."report"."requested_at" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '48 HOURS' AND NOW()  - INTERVAL '24 HOURS'
    GROUP BY
      "reports"."report"."type",
    ORDER BY
      "count" DESC,
      "reports"."report"."type" ASC,
  ) AS today_report_count
  ON today_report_count.type = yesterday_report_count.type

I tried using coalesce() in the select statement but it seems that the "missing" values are not actually considered null.

ORDER BY without TOP/LIMIT not at the outermost level does nothing. Whatever you think it's doing, it's not. PS Please always use a tiny mnemonic table alias with every column reference.

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

A MRE includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. But it's clear that your "values propagated" doesn't require any of the code you wrote good or bad, just code & i/o of a few lines. But further it's obvious that that task will have been asked & answered as a beginner question long ago.

Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Use COALESCE(). For example:
select
  coalesce(t.a, u.a) as a,
  coalesce(t.b, 0) as tb,
  coalesce(t.a, u.a) as a, -- no need to repeat this, but if you must...
  coalesce(u.b, 0) as ub 
from t
full join u on u.a = t.a

Result:
 a  tb   a  ub  
 -- ---- -- --- 
 A  100  A  120 
 B  200  B  0   
 C  0    C  300 

See running example at db<>fiddle.
